# How to add "AR" elements over video?

Tags: video, editing, post-production, compositing

disclaimer: I'm completely a neophyte, mildly competent with Photoshop and that's it.

I was trying to figure out what would be the quickest/easiest way to add AR-ish elements over a video. For example if in the video there is a landmark like a historic building I would like to have a "marker" composited over the middle of the face of this building. Would the gps/compass data of the camera that recorded the video help in any way?

Comment: This doesn't quite seem to be about video as much as it is about coding. If I knew anything about AR, which I don't, I would use scripting to "listen" to the video time, then other scripting (the AR stuff) would trigger based on that time.

Answer (score 1):

I produced a video on Augmented Reality, for a large corporation that spearheaded the technology. We used After Effects to simulate a lot of effects.

We shot our plates and scenes, and when necessary we added dots on sticks for tracking points.

Then, you can take your footage into AE, latch motion trackers to the dots (if your scene doesnt have points sharp enough to tack to), and once you track the motion, you can nest your AR graphics, either static (photoshop psd files), or animated, and they will move with the camera movement, as if in the scene.

If you want to go the extra mile, you can make the AR layers 3D, and add a camera, and using multiple tracking points get your AR graphics to move in 3D, with axis tilting.

You can also add things like Depth of Field.

And lastly, you can have them build on and build off using the built in transitions in AE under Animation... there are 100s.

Hope this helps, Its more than one could explain here, but there are a lot of youtube videos on how to use motion trackers, 3D layers, etc- so if you look into the keywords I gave you, hopefully it will get you started.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think not. AR-ish sounds like to want to elude something, here I think locking down the camera and simply generating the AR-elements in photoshop/illustrator, or if moving AR elements are cqlled for, After Effects and compositing them in premiere or After Effects would get you where I think you want to go. If the video is shot and not locked-down, you can try using the tracking tools in after-effects to allign the AR elements with your source footage.

For inspiration have a peek at this reel; I think many of thes effects follow this general principle: